# how to create a triangle clickable div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a triangle clickable button like div, in the attached image is what I want to actually achieve. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib5WN.png)

This is what I've reached so far,[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dajin007/nA6yn/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="input"><</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {padding:40px;}

.input {   
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px 10px;    
background:#117ebb;
font-size:9px;
color:#fff;
border-radius:5.5px 0px 0px 5px;
box-shadow:  0px 5px 3px #003355;
position:relative;
width:1px;
height:12px;
}

.input:after {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:-10px;
content:" ";
width: 0;
height: 0px;
border-top: 13px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
border-right:13px solid #117ebb;
border-radius:0px 0px 0px 20px; 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can wrap the `<` with `<a>` and make it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

css pure triangle and with jquery you could add click events:

html

```
<div class="input"></div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input").click(function(){
        alert('hello arrow');        
    });
});
```

css

```
body {padding:40px;}
.input{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

    border-right:10px solid blue; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TvJ6t/

Comment: The whole rectangular area (including invisible part) is clickable, not just the actual triangle.